# How to run backfill job with puckel/airflow image

Tags: docker, airflow

I use puckel/airflow image with localexecutor.
I'm trying to run a backfill job

```
docker exec -it 44d0222c71c1 airflow backfill transfer_pipeline -s 2020-05-30 -e 2020-09-01
```

From the log i receive it looks like it's using an SequentialExecutor  and cannot access the postgre database

```
{{cli_action_loggers.py:107}} WARNING - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2020-09-15 23:36:52.316415', 'transfer_pipeline', None, 'cli_backfill', None, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "44d0222c71c1", "full_command": "[\'/usr/local/bin/airflow\', \'backfill\', \'transfer_pipeline\', \'-s\', \'2020-05-30\', \'-e\', \'2020-09-01\']"}')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
[2020-09-15 23:36:52,374] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: job
[SQL: INSERT INTO job (dag_id, state, job_type, start_date, end_date, latest_heartbeat, executor_class, hostname, unixname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('transfer_pipeline', 'running', 'BackfillJob', '2020-09-15 23:37:01.495813', None, '2020-09-15 23:37:01.495833', 'SequentialExecutor', '44d0222c71c1', 'airflow')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass connection via environment variable (`-e` option).

```
docker exec -it \
-e AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@{Your postgres DB Host}:5432/airflow \
44d0222c71c1 airflow backfill transfer_pipeline -s 2020-05-30 -e 2020-09-01
```